# Remove left category menu from home page?

Tags: xml, menu, magento-1.7

I am trying to remove left category menu from homepage. I created local.xml file and added below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version = "0.1.0">
    <default>
        <cms_index_index>
            <reference name="left">
               <block name="home-page-block">
                 <remove name="catalog.leftnav">
               </block>
              </reference>
           </cms_index_index>
    </default>
</layout>
```

i also tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version = "0.1.0">
    <default>
        <cms_index_index>
            <reference name="left">
               <block name="home-page-block">
                 <remove name="catalog.leftnav">
               </block>
              </reference>
           </cms_index_index>
    </default>
```

But this is not working. How to remove? what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i win with css

```
<style>
.col-left .nav-container{display:none}
</style>
```

added code in admin panel (home page layout)